# What do the time jumps in the log files mean? Or: What eats up the time?

Tags: google-app-engine, logging

In my GAE logs (seen from the browser) I often have strange "time jumps". Here is an example:

```
2011-11-15 23:55:05.999
org.xydra.store.impl.gae.changes.SharedRevisionManager getLastCommitted: 
| <<< | [.sr]{'lastCommited'} = {101}
D 2011-11-15 23:55:05.999
org.xydra.store.impl.gae.changes.RevisionCache2 getLastCommited: 
| <<< | [.rc-cDOL]{'lastCommitted'} = {101}
D 2011-11-15 23:55:06.069
org.xydra.store.impl.gae.changes.GaeChangesServiceImpl2 getCachedChange: 
| <<< | [.c2]/gae-data/phonebook/-/-{'15'} = GaeChange {rev:15 lastAct:-1 status:FailedPreconditions <Entity     
D 2011-11-15 23:55:06.069
org.xydra.store.impl.gae.changes.SharedRevisionManager getLastCommitted: 
| <<< | [.sr]{'lastCommited'} = {101}
```

Its some kind of loop doing always the same stuff. However, at some unpredictable point my app suddenly spends a large amount of time doing something unlogged (from 05.999 to 06.069).

I have no clue where that time is spend. I tried adding tons of logging, but had no luck. It seems also to happen in other parts of my app.
Things I considered as possible time-eaters:
    * Bugs in logging of GAE. So I added my own time-measurement, got the same result.
    * Async calls to datastore or memcache - seems weird that of about 100 calls almost all return in less than 1 ms and another call then needs suddenly 70 ms.

*What else might eat up the time? Who else has encountered this?*

Comment: Wait, what, milli-minutes? Do you have links to statement from Google about that? I always thought it was in milliseconds.

Comment: Ouch. It seems I had pre-coffee-syndrome. Of course its milliseconds. Fixed question.

Comment: Ah, you have my sympathy. Could you try putting the milliseconds itself from System.currentTimeMillis() into the log string? I sometimes have this behavior too, but I always assume it's because GAE buffer several log entries before writing them, making the log timestamp appears to be staggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely due to time-slicing. When your app uses up its CPU timeslice, it's put to sleep for a short period until it gets another.